# Laravel 5.2 - bootstrap/cache/services.php missing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

After I ran composer update/ install then when I run php artisan cache:clear. I got the following error.

[ErrorException]                                                                                                                   file_put_contents({application-root-path}/bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Is there any command able to re-cache the file? As for now no matter what php artisan function that I run also will caught into the same error.

p/s: Please comment below if you need me to provide any further information for debug use.

Comment: php artisan command run your application in CLI. When application run in CLI that time we can't use some server variable and many more. So that is causing that error. Please check your code and see where you use `file_put_contents()` function in application.

Answer (score 32):

make sure to run this command:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Alright, thanks ! If directory isn't found, create it by doing `mkdir bootstrap/cache`.

Comment: Don't set 777 on that folder, instead set the right group and only allow write access to that group. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/987864

Comment: Valid response for 5.4. I recently got caught on this after upgrading from 5.3.

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 16):

Just type:

```
cd bootstrap/
mkdir cache
cd .. 
composer install
```

Comment: For security, the official recommendation is that composer never be run as root or sudo. Detailed reasoning is provided here: https://getcomposer.org/root

Answer (score 10):

run this command

```
php artisan optimize --force
```

it will create **services.php** and **compiled.php**

Comment: As of  Laravel 5.5, PHP artisan optimize is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem this way:
If there is a cache directory, delete it and recreate it

Answer (score 0):

Simple go to **bootstrap** folder and create new folder name **cache** :)

right click cache folder and checked

*Folder is ready for archiving*